# How to end Windows lock on file in ODBC connection?

Tags: ms-access, sqlite, linked-list, odbc, dsn

I am using Access to import data from a series of SQLite 3 databases that are all structured the same. I have a system/user DSN for "Import.db". My Access DB has linked tables to those in Import.db.

My goal is to import the data via the linked tables into Access tables, then delete Import.db, then copy the next SQLite3 DB to the same location and call it Import.db, and then keep repeating the process till all are imported.

I took this approach because I don't know how to create DSNs on the fly and link tables for SQLite3 dbs. SQL Server, yes, but not SQLite3. So I thought, just use the same DSN but change the actual file.

The trouble is, after opening my Access DB and opening the linked tables, Access creates a Windows file lock on Import.db. So I can't delete and replace it. Instead, I can import one, then close Access, reopen Access, and repeat. Not so hot.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the connection string of a linked table with:

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyLinkedTable").Connect
```

You now have the information you need to create a query that imports without a linked table.

You might get something like this:

```
ODBC;DSN=SQLite3;Database=Z:\Docs\Import.db;StepAPI=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;
NoTXN=0;Timeout=;ShortNames=0;LongNames=0;NoCreat=0;NoWCHAR=0;
FKSupport=0;JournalMode=;OEMCP=0;LoadExt=;BigInt=0;
```

But you probably won't need most of it, so:

```
sODBC = "[ODBC;DSN=SQLite3;Database=Z:\Docs\Import.db;]"
''Create table query, but append and update are also easy enough
sSQL = "SELECT * INTO SQLite_Import FROM " & sODBC & ".SQLiteTableNameHere"

CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```